# MFC PrintWindow(CPaintDC) works but PrintWindow(CDC) doesnt

Tags: c++, mfc, cwnd

I'm implementing a Printing Function in a big Project to print so called gadgets (derived from CWnd). In the Gadget Class I've created a Function to Render it to the Device Context

```
PrintPageContent(CDC * pDC, const CRect & rContent, int page, int numPages) {
    PrintWindow(pDC, PW_CLIENTONLY);
    pDC->Rectangle(rContent.left,rContent.top, rContent.right, rContent.bottom);
```

To Render the Gadget easily I thought about using the PrintWindow Function
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x51z0shh.aspx

But this only works when Rendering the PrintPreview. When I'm actually Printing it wont. In both cases the same Function is called and the only Thing that differs is that in case of the Preview -> "CDC *  pDC" is a "CPaintDC" Object and in Case of the Actual Printing its a "CDC" Object.

To be sure that its really the "PrintWindow" function what wont work I added another Line of Code to the Function [pDC->Rectangle(...);] which I can see in the Preview as well as on Paper.

I also thought about using the CWnd::Print or CWnd::PrintClient Function but none of them work in both cases.

So my Question is what can I do as a Workaround or what could be the Cause why rendering an Object (derived from CWnd) wont work on a CDC but on a CPaintDC?

Comment: To do proper printing you need to call CPrintDialog, it gives you DC to the printer, you print on that DC the same way as print on display DC. You also have to adjust for differences between screen and printer coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the Problem isn't the CDC/CpaintDC.
It just wont work for the Printers I tested it in the first place.
I tried another Printer and it worked.

I have created another Question for the "REAL" problem
[MFC Printing with CDC just works on some Printers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996167/mfc-printing-with-cdc-just-works-on-some-printers)

Answer (score 1):

An [CPaintDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a48eab8d.aspx) calls CWnd::BeginPaint on construction, and CWnd::EndPaint on destruction, so manually calling those on the CDC might work.

Comment: I did:
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    this->BeginPaint(&ps);
    PrintWindow(pDC, PW_CLIENTONLY);
    this->EndPaint(&ps);
but this wont work...